# joins in Linq using lists<strings> with no id to index from

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, join

Hi and thanks in advance.

I have 2 lists:

```
    String[] a = new String []{"A","B", "C"}; 
    String[] num = new String []{"1","2" ,"3"};
```

And a linq query:

```
    var gridview = (from A in a
                    from num in Num
                    select new
                    {
                        TName = A,
                        RName = Num

                    }).Distinct().ToList();

    GridViewList.DataSource = gridview;
    GridViewList.DataBind();
```

So this generates output like:

```
1 A
2 A
3 A
1 B
2 B
3 B
1 C
2 C
3 C
```

What I want is output like:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

So I thought I could use a join but how if I don't have an id to refer to?

**Change to:**

```
   var gridview = a.Zip(num, (t, r) => new 
   {
       TName = t,
       RName = r
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone... I think its working, I am just getting this weird output in each row: "System.String[]"

Comment: ok fix it... thanks...just forgot to change parameter names inside the zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do here is Zip the lists

```
var gridview = a.Zip(num, (A,n)=>new{TName = A,RName = n}).ToList();
```

See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am getting weird output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Zip`:

```
var result = a.Zip(num, (s, n) => n.ToString() + " " + s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Zip` not `Join`, assuming the requirement is to merge two lists of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following approach:

```
var res = a.Select((x,i) => new {TName = x, RName = num[i]}).ToList();
```